# Magento Mobile HTML5 1.9

Tags: php, html, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

We have installed the HTML5 Mobile Magento Theme on our store.

It all works now except one thing, on the category page the header doesn't work properly.

This is an example of the working page:

[image]

This is an example of a page that doesn't work:

[image]

I have discovered that if I remove the following lines from the inspect element, it then works.

`<div class="wrapper">`

`<div class="page">`

How can I change this in the template or layout xml so that it saves this change ?

Comment: Well, erm – change the template? If do not know how the Magento templating system works, leave your fingers from it and hire an expert to that for you. I guess the two elements will occur in many template files. But on the other hand – if this is an default installation, what did have changed before, that it does work anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol what a great response from feeela

I think the question is more around what template files the magento mobile theme uses from the default theme files and which ones are overwritten.

telling someone on stackoverflow to hire someone isnt really a good answer is it??

in this case it looks like you are trying to load a template file that isnt in your mobile theme folder.

check the other templates to see which file is loading using template hints. it might be that the mobile theme doesnt have the right layout file for that page.

1. check on your mobile with template hints on
2. find out which file is loading on the broken page
3. ensure the mobile theme contains that layout file with the correct name to override the default / base theme in that case

Comment: Thank you for that, and yeah. His comment wasn't very helpful, the problem was that it was loading the 2column layout from the base directory rather than the right one from the mobile directory, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem when I introduced this mobile theme to my Magento webstore.

My solution was just copy the 1column.phtml and rename it 2columns-left.phtml and 2-columns-right.phtml than everything worked perfectly, minus the "Add to Cart" button which I am still having issues with.

I am sure this is not the correct way to implement this but it was fast and simple.